# Change US1 to IE1 for SIP Endpoint Registration

Tags: twilio

When I register a SIP phone using:

```
USER@SIP-DOMAIN.sip.us1.twilio.com
```

It works.

However if I try to register a phone using 'ie1' for Irelend, it doesn't work:

```
USER@SIP-DOMAIN.sip.ie1.twilio.com
```

This page in Twilio Docs implies that this should be possible:

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sending-sip-how-it-works
```

This page in the Twilio Control Panel shows us1 but doesn't mention other locales:

```
https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/endpoints/ID
```

.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that while you can use the localized SIP endpoints to connect to a PBX, as the documentation on [sending SIP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/sending-sip-how-it-works) says, [SIP registration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/pv-sip-registration) is currently [only possible in our US1 data centre](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twilio-sip/pv-sip-registration#sip-register).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Will this create latency with calls?  Or only with registration?

Comment: If two UK legs are connected, does the call have to travel through US servers?

Comment: Since the registration is in the US, then yes, the call will go via the US. I'd recommend testing to see what the latency is like.

Comment: ok.  Is there an ETA to enable SIP registration endpoints in UK, IE or Europe?

Comment: I have nothing that I can share regarding SIP registration outside of US1 right now.

Comment: Is it something that is on the roadmap at all?

Comment: I can't share anything publicly about the roadmap for this feature, but I have submitted this question as feedback so that the team can prioritise better.

Comment: Thank you for your help!